# A better way of writing this particular SELECT query in a VIEW

Tags: sql, select, view, case

I would like to know if there is a better way of writing the `SELECT` clause in the query below. There are three possible cases for `status`. It can either have a value of 'A' or 'N' or null.

I think that placing the `AND status = 'A'` in the where clause is redundant when you are comparing the subTable values to a value of 'A'. Is there any way that this could be rewritten more efficiently? I feel like restricting the status in the `WHERE` clause is always going to give you an 'A' and hence pointless to do the `CASE` statement.

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.st_review_status_vw AS
(
    SELECT c.st_id, c.ms_price_comp_fy, 
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT status FROM 
                    (SELECT st_id, status, ms_price_comp_fy
                     FROM ms_price_comp
                     WHERE st_id = c.st_id 
                         AND ms_price_comp_fy = c.ms_price_comp_fy 
                         AND status = 'A'
                     GROUP BY st_id, status, ms_price_comp_fy)
                 AS subTable) = 'A' THEN 'C'
            ELSE 'I'
        END AS status,
        MAX(date_approved) AS date_completed
    FROM ms_price_comp AS c
    GROUP BY c.st_id, c.ms_price_comp_fy
)
```

Comment: "the WHERE clause is always going to give you an 'A'" - not necessarily; the innermost sub-select might return no records, so the selected status in the outer sub-select would be NULL; the CASE item would then evaluate as 'I'.

Comment: Are the rows with `status='A'` the same as those with `MAX(date_appoved)` ?

Comment: you mean in that case it will fall into the "ELSE" clause right...? well in that case then yes, but what i mean is that isn't it redundant to put the status = 'A' in the WHERE clause and then compare status to 'A' in the subTable

Comment: @ypercube - yes the date_approved is in the same table as the status. not sure what you mean by the 'same' though..

Comment: @user1060096: No, it's not redundant. The redundancy is the (unneeded) correlated subquery. One way to avoid it, is Luis' solution.

Comment: @user1060096: I meant: For all groups of rows with same `st_id, ms_price_comp_fy`, is this true: `the row with the maximum date_approved has status 'A'` or `there is no row with status 'A'`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.st_review_status_vw AS (
SELECT c.st_id, c.ms_price_comp_fy, 

    CASE WHEN MIN(status)  = 'A' THEN 'C'
    ELSE 'I'
    END AS status,

MAX(date_approved) AS date_completed
FROM ms_price_comp AS c
GROUP BY c.st_id, c.ms_price_comp_fy
)
```

Comment: `MIN()` can be used with text fields: `MIN('A', 'N', 'N', NULL) = 'A'`.

Comment: @user1060096: You can tick the answer that was most helpful.

Comment: @ypercube what i mean is that if the "searched" status is 'K' instead of 'A' and other valids status are 'J' and 'M' then the expresion: 
        CASE WHEN `MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'K' then 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0` THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'I'
        END AS status
is the generic way to solve the problem

Comment: @LuisSiquot: Yes, that's a solution to the more general problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be the same to me

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.st_review_status_vw AS (
SELECT
        c.st_id
    ,   c.ms_price_comp_fy
    ,   CASE
            WHEN MIN(status) = 'A' THEN 'C'
            ELSE 'I'
        END AS status
    ,   MAX(date_approved) AS date_completed
FROM ms_price_comp AS c
GROUP BY c.st_id, c.ms_price_comp_fy
)
```

Comment: There could me more than one rows with same `st_id` and `ms_price_comp_fy`. The `WHEN status = 'A'` will test an arbitary row from them.